# what is *A record

Tags: dns

We have 3 A record on our DNS hosting, what is the difference between
1- A   *            129.122.21.21
2- A   example.co   129.122.21.21
3- A   www          129.122.21.21

Comment: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname() [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have the domain `foo.com`

- `*` matches all subdomains - `www.foo.com, xyz.foo.com`
- www matches only `www` - `www.foo.com`
- example.co matches only `example.co.foo.com`

Answer (score 0):

So in essence, you only require entry number 1?